# ORACLE: Select de MAX value in column 2 after selected de MAX value in column 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table T in ORACLE with values:

```
cod1 cod2  A   B
==================
A    AA    2   0
A    AB    2   2
B    BB    1   2
A    AA    3   0
A    AA    3   1
B    BB    2   1
```

I want return the records (cod1 cod2) with MAX(B) of MAX(A).
For example:

```
A    AA    3   1
A    AB    2   2
B    BB    2   1
```

Is this possible?

```
select cod1, cod2, MAX(B) 
from T
group by cod1, cod2
where (cod1, cod2, A) IN (
   select cod1, cod2, MAX(A) 
   from T
   group by cod1, cod2
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here with a two level sort:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cod1, cod2, A, B,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cod1, cod2 ORDER BY A DESC, B DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT cod1, cod2, A, B
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do simple aggregation :

```
select cod1, cod2, max(a), max(b)
from t
group by cod1, cod2;
```

If you want full records then you can use *correlated* subquery :

```
select t.*
from t 
where t.b = (select t1.b
             from t t1 
             where t1.cod1 = t.cod1 and t1.cod2 = t.cod2
             order by t1.a desc, t1.b desc
             fetch first 1 rows only
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

*(continuation of the resolution of the initial question)*

And if i want to return the table with other column "MAXs" with "1" or "0" ?

example:

```
cod1 cod2  A   B   MAXs
=======================
 A    AA   2   0    0
 A    AB   2   2    1
 B    BB   1   2    0
 A    AA   3   0    0
 A    AA   3   1    1
 B    BB   2   1    1
```